# if the number $K$ has $45$ divisors, and the number $K^2$ has $M$ divisors, what is the sum of all possible values of $M$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-counting-function

> if the number  $K$ has $45$ divisors, and the number $K^2$ has $M$  divisors, what is the sum of all possible  values  of $M$?

My try follows.

$45=15×3$   ;    $45 =  45×1$  ;  $45 = 9×5$ .

Then $k$ has $3$ possible  prime factorizations :

$K= p^{14} ×q^2$ and so $k^2= p^{28}×q^4$  so  #of divisors of $K^2 = 29×5=145$ .

In the same manner

$K^2$ would have $89$ or $17×9=153$ divisors

So the sum of all possible values  of $M$ is $89+145+153= 387$.

Is my answer right?

If not, please help me understand my fault. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Obviously, only positive divisors are counted; otherwise, since 45 is odd, there is no possible $K$, and the requested sum is zero.

Comment: @fgrieu   yes you are right  , positive divisors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right lines. You've correctly found that $145$, $89$ and $153$ are possible values for the number of divisors of $K^2$. However, there is another possibility since $K^2$ could have *three* different prime factors.

Comment: which  is ....??

Comment: $45=3\times 3\times 5$, so it could be $p^2q^2r^4$.

Comment: yes you are right;  so the sum =$45+387 =432$

Comment: @Medo The fourth one should be 225 not 45 as you are doing $(2\cdot2+1)(2\cdot2+1)(2\cdot4+1)=225$. The total is therefore 612.

Comment: @Ian Miller   IS that because  they are even  ; is this a rule ?

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to about evenness. The math is as follows: In the fourth case you have $p^2q^2r^4$ from $(2+1)(2+1)(4+1)=45$ divisors. Once you square it you get $p^4q^4r^8$ so you get $(4+1)(4+1)(8+1)=225$ divisors.